# Converting from .lyr to .kmz with error and shifted pixels in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, raster-conversion, kmz

I had the .tif file and by using "Layer to kml" toolbox (without changing the preset parameters) i got the kmz file with very bad resolution. Then i tried to modify it changing the values for output image properties. But the results is strange, instead of having the same cell size i got this weird shifted/overlapped pixels. Scale and all other parameters stayed the same, only the output image properties that were changed..

Have you ever met this problem?

[image: this is the original tif file]
[image: converted into kmz]

Comment: What were the precise steps that you performed (tools and parameter values) to see this?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this does happen, unfortunately... you can try to minimize the change of cell values by;

1. Project your original raster layer to WGS84 beforehand. (At least this gives you a chance to choose interpolation method fit for your purpose). Do not leave projection process to this tool.
2. `Layer To KML` has `Output Image Properties`. This allows you to specify the `Size of returned image (pixels)`. Use a multiple of your raster size (columns or rows).
3. Setting higher DPI may also help (i have not tried).

Still, we cannot have much hope for a perfect translation to KML.